# Can I hide my password for data at rest encryption key?

Tags: security, encryption, mariadb

For MariaDB encryption at-rest, my setting is

```
[mysqld]
# at-rest encryption
plugin_load_add              = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/rest/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey  = FILE:/etc/mysql/rest/keyfile.passwd
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CBC
```

However, if hackers steals the database, they has access to both `keyfile.enc` and `keyfile.passwd` and the point of encryption at-rest is useless.

Can I tell the key manager not to read the super password from the file. Instead, read it from the user at the startup?

Comment: The only options are those [documented](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually database is started as a service in background, so entering keys at startup will not be possible.

To separate key(s) and data you have the following options:

- store keys on a separate device which can be unplugged after start of database server.
- use an external key management system, e.g [Eperi](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/eperi-key-management-encryption-plugin/) which also supports key rotation.

Comment: Is `AWS Key Management Plugin` similar to `Eperi` in this sense? There is no much information in the link about how Eperi connects to another server. A bit hard to evaluate it.